# In Gnome builder, "Create Project" button is inactive when JavaScript is selected

Tags: gnome, application-development, gnome-builder

When I try to create a new project in Gnome Builder the `Create Project` button is inactive if I select `JavaScript` and `GNOME Application`. If I switch to `GNOME Application (Legacy)` or some other language it works.

[image: Screenshot with inactive "Create Project" button]

`gjs (1.64.5-0ubuntu0.20.04.01)` is installed, Gnome Builder was installed using Flatpak (not sure if that is important).